# How to get particular tag names from ID of parent tag from xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, canvas

I am displaying records from XML file using JavaScript AJAX on canvas. My intention is to show child records from particular parent tag id instead of full list.

**XML file:**

```
<Content>
 <pages>
  <page id="1">
   <flag id="1">
    <lang id="eng">
       <img>img/abc1.PNG</img>
    </lang>
    <lang id="eng">
       <img>img/abc2.PNG</img>
    </lang>
    <lang id="eng">
       <img>img/abc3.PNG</img>
    </lang>
   </flag>
  </page>

 <page id="2">
  <flag id="1">
   <lang id="eng">
     <img>img/xyz1.PNG</img>
     <img>img/xyz2.PNG</img>
   </lang>
  </flag>
 </page>

 </pages>
</Content>
```

I want to get image name where page id="1"

Expected output:

```
img/abc1.PNG
img/abc2.PNG
img/abc3.PNG
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the XML to JSON converter at https://code.google.com/p/x2js/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
var xmlString = '<Content><pages> <page id="1">  <flag id="1">   <lang id="eng">       <img>img/abc1.PNG</img>    </lang>    <lang id="eng">       <img>img/abc2.PNG</img>    </lang>    <lang id="eng">       <img>img/abc3.PNG</img>    </lang>   </flag>  </page> <page id="2">  <flag id="1">   <lang id="eng">     <img>img/xyz1.PNG</img>     <img>img/xyz2.PNG</img>   </lang>  </flag> </page> </pages></Content>',
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc);
for (var i = 0; i < $xml.find("page").length; i++) {
  if ($($xml.find("page")[i]).attr('id') == 1) {
    alert($($xml.find("page")[i]).find('img').text());
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope some little changes make it work for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to say that, my XML data will be dynamic. I am handling same XML structure format with different records. Now I am reading XML file using Ajax.